# How to call a GP service from ArcObjects in .NET using ArcGIS Engine 10.2?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-engine, geoprocessing-service

I published and successfully accessed a GP service in ArcMap 10.2, but I couldn't make it work in my .NET program using ArcObjects 10.2:

```c#
        IGeoProcessor gp = new GeoProcessorClass();
        gp.AddToolbox(@"http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services;mygpfolder/testsel");

        //input
        IGPUtilities2 gputils = new GPUtilitiesClass();
        IFeatureClass fc = (IFeatureClass)gputils.OpenDatasetFromLocation(@"E:\input.shp");
        IRecordSetInit recordset = new RecordSetClass();
        recordset.SetSourceTable((ITable)fc, null);
        IGPRecordSet gprecordset = new GPFeatureRecordSetLayerClass();
        gprecordset.RecordSet = (IRecordSet)recordset;

        IGPFeatureRecordSetLayer recordlayer = new GPFeatureRecordSetLayerClass();
        recordlayer = gprecordset as IGPFeatureRecordSetLayer;

        IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();
        parameters.Add(recordlayer);

        gp.Execute("Select", parameters, null);
```

I got "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component." at "gp.Execute".  The GP service is published using tool "Select" under toolbox "Analysis" in ArcMap:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The tool is called [Select_analysis](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000005000000), there are a few things called 'select' and you have to specify the one you want. The vague error doesn't help but it can't find a geoprocessing tool called 'select'.

```
gp.Execute("Select_analysis", parameters, null);
```

it may be worth noting that a geoprocessor tool returns a value of type [IGeoProcessorResult](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002n00000107000000) which you can get your messages using [GetResultMessages](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/GetResultMessages_Method/002n0000011r000000/). This will at least give you some inkling why the tool failed.

Comment: Hi Michael,it shows the same error with "Select_analysis",and I updated the post with a screen shot of the service.I just assumed that I should use the name under Tasks

Comment: Is your ArcGis server licensed for geoprocessing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ArcGIS server so I'm not sure what do you mean by licensed? but I coulde execute the GP service via web browser and arcmap

Comment: Then it must be. The basic level of license for ArcGis server does not include geoprocessing http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf (page 2) have a look at the result object and see if you get some messages there, that might help.